# how to make a function set a value of property from FALSE to TRUE

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing this project using angular where I have a collection of JSON objects carrying properties and values. All objects have a property **done** with value set to **FALSE**

```
  myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope){
    $scope.customers = [
  {'name':'Ali','link':'https://facebook.com','done':false, 'call': 0},
  {'name':'khaled','link':'https://google.com','done':false, 'call': 0},
  {'name':'Salim','link':'https://technet.com','done':false, 'call': 0}
  ]
```

A button in the HTML page is supposed to call a function **upCall(customer)**

```
   <div ng-repeat="customer in customers | orderBy: '-call'">
      <button ng-click="upCall(customer)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></button>
```

The button is supposed to invoke the **upCall(customer)** function below

```
$scope.upCall = function(customer) {
  return customer.done === true;
}
```

However, when debugging the browser, the button never sets the property of the object to **TRUE**

Is the syntax which I should be worried about

Comment: you want to change the property from false to true ? So why are you comparing customer.done === true ?

Comment: below both answers are good ! you can choose any one :) . quick

Comment: The only problem you have is that you are comparing `===` rather than assigning `=` the value `true`. You also don't need to return anything from `$scope.upCall`. The approaches suggested below are actually sub-optimal. The one where `$index` is returned, ordering would break it. And the other one returning the child scope is quite unnecessary.

Comment: @squiroid
it was a typo error dear.
I was only planning to set the value of the property from false to true.

This was achieved  thankfully using the $index service :)

Answer (score 0):

try `this` option

```
<div ng-repeat="customer in customers | orderBy: '-call'">
      <button ng-click="upCall(**this**)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></button>


$scope.upCall = function(customerContext) {
  **customerContext.done = true;**
  return customerContext;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`return customer.done === true;` this statement checks whether `customer.done` is exactly equal to `true`.which will return `false`.you are not mutating the `customer.done`.so

```
return customer.done = true;
```